# Can't connect Ngxin reverse proxy to Gunicorn on Django container (Docker)

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I've being trying to make a stack with a Nginx container receiving requests as a reverse proxy to my Django container with Gunicorn (not worrying about static files or DB for now), but I keep getting a **502 Bad Gateway** error on Nginx.

Nginx logs:

```
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.12.0
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 6.3.0 20170205 (Debian 6.3.0-6) 
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.4.0-63-generic
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 7
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 8
2017/04/28 12:10:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 9
172.19.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2017:12:10:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
2017/04/28 12:10:17 [error] 7#7: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.53.53:8000/", host: "localhost"
2017/04/28 12:10:28 [info] 7#7: *1 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 172.19.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/04/28 12:10:28 [info] 7#7: *4 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 172.19.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/04/28 12:10:28 [info] 7#7: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 172.19.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

Gunicorn:

```
[2017-04-28 12:09:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-04-28 12:09:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2017-04-28 12:09:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-04-28 12:09:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2017-04-28 12:09:02 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2017-04-28 12:09:02 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
```

Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM nginx:stable
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 3;

events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream app_servers {
        server app:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile for django:

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

ADD . /code

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

CMD ["gunicorn", "marcos.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "3"]
```

I've tried to create a network manually and placing both containers in it running the following commands.

```
docker run --network marcos_net -h app marcos
docker run --network marcos_net -h nginx -p 80:80 nginx
```

And with a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'  
services:  
  app:
    image: myrepo/app
  nginx:
    image: myrepo/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
```

I've also tried to access the containers to ping one another like it says in the docs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/) and they are in fact in the same network. Also checked with the `docker network inspect` command.

Both ways log the same error printed above.

I've seen some similar questions, but they are from different docker-compose file versions, and they didn't solve the problem for me, so I don't think it is the same problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your nginx isn't connected to gunicorn properly. Try putting port parameter in your docker compose file.

```
services:  
  app:
    image: myrepo/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Also, here is an example of how you may set it up.

https://github.com/wiamsuri/django-gunicorn-nginx-docker